# How to write MS Word macro using dynamic data source for OpenDataSource?

Tags: excel, vba

for a MailMerge in Microsoft Word I wanna open a data source to work with it. Currently it looks like this:

```
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:= _
    "C:\Folder1\Folder2\CustomerXY\Exceldata.xlsx"
```

What I wanna do now it turning the macro into one using a dynamic data source: The macro should take the Exceldata.xlsx from that folder, where the Word-File is also in...

So when I'm using the Word-file from folder CustomerXY, the macro uses the Excel-file from CustomerXY - and if it's Word-file from CustomerYZ, it also uses that one from YZ.

Anyone an idea? I thougt of using CurDir first, but this didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Simply ask the `ActiveDocument` for its path:

```
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:= _
    ActiveDocument.Path & "\Exceldata.xlsx"
```